# Issues with cv::forEach() in my image to ASCII algorithm. How can I fix it?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to improve my original algorithm by using `cv::forEach()`. The original code works great, but the `forEach()`  code is outputting characters in seemingly random orders. This is the original code:

```cpp
// Grayscale pixel values with corresponding ASCII characters
std::unordered_map<int, char> brightness_map;
for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
{
if (i < 30)
brightness_map[i] = ' ';
else if (i < 55)
brightness_map[i] = '.';
else if (i < 85)
brightness_map[i] = ':';
else if (i < 115)
brightness_map[i] = '-';
else if (i < 140)
brightness_map[i] = '=';
else if (i < 165)
brightness_map[i] = '/';
else if (i < 180)
brightness_map[i] = 'o';
else if (i < 210)
brightness_map[i] = '0';
else
brightness_map[i] = '@';
}
// Outputting ASCII characters based on the brightness of the pixel
cv::uint8_t gray;
std::cout << "\n\n\n\n\n";
for (int r = 0; r < frame.rows; r++)
for (int c = 0; c < frame.cols; c++)
{
gray = frame.at<uint8_t>(cv::Point(c, r));
std::cout << brightness_map[gray];
if (c >= frame.cols)
std::cout << "\n";
}
```

This is the new and broken code:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<int, char> brightness_map;
for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
{
if (i < 30)
brightness_map[i] = ' ';
else if (i < 55)
brightness_map[i] = '.';
else if (i < 85)
brightness_map[i] = ':';
else if (i < 115)
brightness_map[i] = '-';
else if (i < 140)
brightness_map[i] = '=';
else if (i < 165)
brightness_map[i] = '/';
else if (i < 180)
brightness_map[i] = 'o';
else if (i < 210)
brightness_map[i] = '0';
else
brightness_map[i] = '@';
}
// Outputting ASCII characters based on the brightness of the pixel
std::cout << "\n\n\n\n\n";
frame.forEach<uint8_t>([&brightness_map, &frame](uint8_t& pixel, const int* position) -> void
{
std::cout << brightness_map[frame.at<uint8_t>(position[0], position[1])];
if (position[1] >= frame.cols)
std::cout << "\n";
});
```

Comment: Have you done anything to try and debug it, like setting a breakpoint and looking at what  `position[0]` and `position[1]` are?

Comment: Yes. They are just the row and column indices. I have also tried outputting brightness_map[pixel], but it doesnt work and the debugger says that pixel is a unicode character, probably because it is uint8_t

Comment: `frame.at<uint8_t>(cv::Point(c, r));` and `frame.at<uint8_t>(position[0], position[1])` aren't the same. Dunno if they do the same thing or not.

Comment: They arent the same, but im pretty sure that they effectively do the same thing, which is accessing the pixel at column, row

Answer (score 2):

The description of `forEach` in [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d) says

> Runs the given functor over all matrix elements in parallel.

Because it runs in parallel, the order of visiting pixels is undefined, you should not expect them to be visited in order.

So, for your use case, you need the explicit loop. You can speed up pixel access by avoiding the `at` method, and instead get the pointer to the beginning of a row (with the `ptr` method) and access all pixels in that row through this pointer.

```cpp
// note: code not tested, typed on a phone, caveat emptor
for (int r = 0; r < frame.rows; r++) {
  uint8_t const* p = frame.ptr<uint8_t>(r);
  for (int c = 0; c < frame.cols; c++) {
    std::cout << brightness_map[p[c]];
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

`cv::Mat` also has a `begin` and `end` methods to make iterating easier, but I think it’s nice to explicitly loop over rows and columns here, because you want to output a newline at the end of each row, which you can easily do if you have a double loop.